# const list, non-const element access

Tags: boost, constants, containers

I've a problem with boost intrusive containers.

One of my classes has an intrusive list of some objects, whose lifetimes are strictly managed by it. The objects themselves are meant to be modified by the users of the class, but they are not supposed to modify the list itself. That's why I'm only providing access to the list through a "getList" function, which returns a const version of the intrusive list.

The problem with const intrusive lists is that the elements also turn out to be const when you're trying to iterate through them. But the users should be able to iterate through and modify the items.

I don't want to keep a separate list of pointers to give to the users, because that would invalidate one of the biggest advantages of using intrusive containers. Namely, the ability to remove items from the container in constant time, while the only thing you have is a pointer to the item.

It would be sad to have to give a non-const version of my list just because of a limitation of C++. So the question is: Is there a special const version of the boost intrusive containers, which magically allows item modifications while disallowing any modifications on the list itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've designed a complete solution to the problem. Andy's solution is nice, if you don't need to iterate over the items in an efficient manner. But I wanted something that's semantically equivalent to const std::list. Maybe it's an overkill, but performance wise there's almost no difference after optimizations:

The solution is to privately extend the intrusive list with a class called ConstList, which exposes just enough to let BOOST_FOREACH iterate, but not to make any changes by anyone. I've moved the list hook from the item to a child class, so that an item object cannot be used to change the list either. We're storing the child class with the hook, but our iterators are returning references to the item class. I've coded this solution into two templated classes for easy application to any item class.

I've made a header file with the ConstList class and the HookedItem class, followed by the tests.cpp, used to test and benchmark. You'll see that our ConstList class has equal performance while iterating.

It works quite cleanly, and the user code also stays clean. Then this begs the question: Why isn't this already in boost????!?!?

Feel free to use the following code for any purpose :)

P.S: I've had a moment of revelation while coming up with this solution: "const" is nothing but a syntactic sugar for a special case of what you can already achieve with the right class hierarchy. Is that true, or was I over-generalizing?

------------------ ConstList.h -----------------------

```
#include <boost/intrusive/list_hook.hpp>

template < typename T>
struct type_wrapper{  typedef T type;};

template<class listType, class owner, class item>
class ConstList: private listType {
    friend class type_wrapper<owner>::type;
public:
    class iterator {
        typename listType::iterator it;
    public:
        typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
        typedef item value_type;
        typedef int difference_type;
        typedef item* pointer;
        typedef item& reference;
        template<class T>
        iterator(const T it): it(it){}
        bool operator==(iterator & otherIt) {return it==otherIt.it;}
        iterator & operator++() {
            it++;
            return *this;
        }
        item & operator*() {
            return *it;
        }
    };
    iterator begin() {
        return iterator(listType::begin());
    }

    iterator end() {
        return iterator(listType::end());
    }
};

template<class item, class owner, class hooktype>
class HookedItem: public item {
    friend class type_wrapper<owner>::type;
public:
    hooktype hook_;
    typedef boost::intrusive::member_hook<HookedItem, hooktype, &HookedItem::hook_> MemberHookOption;
private:
    template<class Arg1, class Arg2>
    HookedItem(Arg1 &arg1, Arg2 &arg2): item(arg1, arg2){}
};
```

------------------ tests.cpp -----------------------

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<boost/checked_delete.hpp>
#include<ConstList.h>
#include<boost/intrusive/list.hpp>
#include<boost/foreach.hpp>

using namespace boost::intrusive;

class myOwner;
class myItem {
public:
    int a,b; //arbitrary members
    myItem(int a, int b): a(a), b(b){};
};

typedef HookedItem<myItem,myOwner,list_member_hook<> > myHookedItem;
typedef list<myHookedItem, typename myHookedItem::MemberHookOption> myItemList;
typedef ConstList<myItemList,myOwner,myItem> constItemList;

class myOwner {
public:
    constItemList constList;
    myItemList & nonConstList;
    myOwner(): nonConstList(constList) {}
    constItemList & getItems() { return constList;}
    myItem * generateItem(int a, int b) {
        myHookedItem * newItem = new myHookedItem(a,b);
        nonConstList.push_back(*newItem);
        return newItem;
    }
    ~myOwner() {nonConstList.clear_and_dispose(boost::checked_delete<myHookedItem>);}
};


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    myOwner owner;
    int avoidOptimization=0;
    for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
        owner.generateItem(i,i);
    }


    clock_t start = clock();
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        BOOST_FOREACH(myItem & item, owner.constList)
            avoidOptimization+=item.a;
    printf ( "%f\n", ( (double)clock() - start ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC );


    start = clock();
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        BOOST_FOREACH(myHookedItem & item, owner.nonConstList)
            avoidOptimization+=item.a;
    printf ( "%f\n", ( (double)clock() - start ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC );


    printf ("%d",avoidOptimization);
    return 0;
}
```

------------ Console Output -----------------

```
4.690000
4.700000
1764472320
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return a list, give an access to separate items by reference

Comment: That's a very nice answer indeed, I'm switching from an stl list of pointers to the intrusive list, that's why my mind was stuck at returning a list. One problem that would arise from this solution is that the users would be able to modify the list using the non-const items themselves. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: OK, I've thought about the following solution to the possibility of manipulating the list through the items: I'll have an "itemBase" class, which doesn't have the list hook and pass instances of that by reference to the users.  While my class's list will keep objects of class "item" which does nothing but inherit from itemBase and list hook. Does that make sense, or am i overlooking something?

Comment: yes, sounds fine. there's also another option (I assume you use `base hooks`): derive privately from `list_base_hook` and declare `boost::intrusive::list<Item>` as a friend in `Item`.

Comment: Just befriending boost::intrusive::list<Item> doesn't seem to help. I still get error: ‘boost::intrusive::detail::node_holder<boost::intrusive::list_node<void*>, world_list_tag, (boost::intrusive::link_mode_type)2u, 1>’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Node’ among a lot of other things.

Comment: you can find which boost classs need an access to `list_base_hook` and add it as a friend (with `boost::intrusive::list` or instead of it). Do it only if you don't like your initial approach of providing a separate base class to limit access